# flask: creating apps in side application says "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Tags: python, flask

I am working on an application, which looks similar in structure as

```
facebook/
         __init__.py
         feed/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
         chat/
             __init__.py
             models.py
             business.py
             views.py
```

My `facebook.__init__.py` is

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import feed.views
import chat.views
```

My `facebook.runserver.py` is

```
from . import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

My `feed.views.py` is

```
from .. import app

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'hello world'
```

My `chat.views.py` is

```
from .. import app

@app.route('/chat')
def chat():
    return 'Let's chat'
```

When I try to run this application, as `python runserver.py`, I see error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook/runserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import app
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put your `runserver.py` outside of the `facebook` folder and make its content as:

```
from facebook import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: it would be nice if this answer was more detailed. I found detailed explanation here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/

Comment: @Richeek link is dead, it's now https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/